# Why are the variables all showing as nil in this AFNetworking block (in swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, nserror

I linked my project up to AFNetwork and have this sample code:

```
var manager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL:     NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org"))

manager.GET("data/2.5/weather", parameters: nil, success:{(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, obj: AnyObject!) in
    println("success!")
        },
        failure:{(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
            println("fail!")
        }
)
```

If I put a breakpoint in success, both obj and operation are "nil" when I do:

```
po operation
po obj
```

But under variables, operation says:

```
operation   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>    0x7b029e30  0x7b029e30
```

obj says:

```
obj Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<AnyObject>    (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x7b02c3b0 -> 0x00ea2940 (void *)0x00ea2954: OBJC_METACLASS_$___NSCFDictionary)   Some
```

Any idea how to print out the values?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in the success closure `println("operation: \(operation)")`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in my Xcode6:

```
frame variable data
(NSDictionary) data = 0x7c4909d0 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = 0x7c48ff20
    value = 0x7c4909a0
  }
}
```

The command is frame variable xxx